# How to Write File PDF to Android 13 Storage in IONIC Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a IONIC Cordova Project. I am facing file storage problem. My code works perfect in all the android devices less than 11 but in android versions greater than 10 its not working.

Comment: What does not work and what is the error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 13 some major changes In the Storage and Media Access [Read Official Document here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13)

Comment: i have write a plugin in android native for taking permission now pdf is getting download.

Comment: @UmarShahzad could you share your solution please? I am facing the same issue. Thanks.